# How to send byte array to server side using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

forgive me if this question is too silly or already asked I googled a lot but I didnt get anything I want. I need to pass a byte array to server side using ajax but its not working as planned my current code is given below

```
var bytes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    bytes.push(data.charCodeAt(i));
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/ImageUpload',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{ data:bytes},
    success: function (response) {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

Upload Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImageUpload(byte[] data)
    {
                ImageModel newImage = new ImageModel();
                ImageDL addImage = new ImageDL();
                newImage.ImageData = data;
                addImage.AddImage(newImage);
                return Json(new { success = true });

    }
```

I know something wrong with my program but I cant find it please help me to solve this

Comment: What does *"Not working as planned"* mean? Are you getting any errors on the page or in your server-side logs?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker no I did't get any errors actually the ajax function was called but it did not invoke the server side method

Comment: Your not implementing array correctly. It should be something like this:

var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";

When you check array length - use <name_of_array>.length

Comment: @Nilzone- There is no problem with the array the array is in correct structure

Comment: Can you post your `Upload` action method?

Comment: @mattytommo please check the question I added the Upload method

Comment: @AlenJoy Hmm, does it hit that method? Have you tried changing to a `string[]` as I think that might be the type being sent.

Comment: @mattytommo yep it actually hits the ajax function but not the Upload method, I tried string[] too but its too not working

Comment: You'll no doubt have to write your own model binder. AFAIK the default model binder doesn't support byte arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Byte to Image conversion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937956/byte-to-image-conversion-not-working)

Comment: Do you see that the name of your method differs from the one you are trying to post to...?

Comment: @AlenJoy Take out `dataType: 'json'` that's not needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/ImageUpload',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{ data: data}, //your string data
    success: function (response) {
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

And in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImageUpload(string data)
    {
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        //other stuff
    }
```